# dataTask of URLSession not running

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm trying to get results from an API, and I'm having trouble running the request itself.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
if let error = error {
        print("error: \(error)")
    } else {
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
        }
        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("data: \(dataString)")
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

However, it doesn't seem to run anything inside the code block in dataTask.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The code is supposed to work, where do you run the code?

Comment: @vadian I'm running it inside a function that is called in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Your code should work. Check the function where you are calling this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well. It seems like you're just calling the function incorrectly...try it this way:

1:

```
    func request() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
            print("error: \(error)")
        } else {
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
            }
            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("data: \(dataString)")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

2:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    request()
}
```

Comment: This is more or less how it is now. I didn't post the entire function because there are some irrelevant code there.

Comment: Ok.  if your function large, maybe something is blocking execution of this part, I'd recommend splitting the execution for checking or using method         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            <#code#>
        }

Answer (score 1):

Try this working for me with data JSONSerialization

> Blockquote

```
func callApi(){
let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (serviceData, urlReponse, error) in
    guard error == nil else{
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    if let response = urlReponse as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print("statusCode \(response.statusCode)")
    }
    if let data = serviceData, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
        print("String Format" + dataString)
    }

    // Data Parse
    
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: serviceData!, options: .mutableContainers)
    let result = jsonData as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    print("Dictionary Format \(result)")
}
task.resume() }
```